# Атомарное изменение ComboBox.Items

Tags: c#, .net

Существует ли способ атомарно изменить коллекцию объектов, содержащуюся в System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Items?

Comment: Поясни что значит атомарно.

Comment: Плюсую. Главная проблема, как я понимаю, именно в этом. Неплохо бы пояснить ее.

Comment: @Павел Зайцев, допустим есть переменная. Её изменение называется атомарным, если в процессе изменения можно увидеть только два состояния: то что было до, и то что стало после. К примеру, если коллекция Combobox.Items пуста, а я хочу видеть в ней три элемента, то добавление их в цикле по одному — неатомарная операция. Атомарно было в памяти создать новую коллекцию и выполнить присваивание combobox.Items = newCollection (C# гарантирует ароматность присваивания указателей). Но вот беда: Items — read only.
А вообще, википедия — она ведь существует.

Comment: Судя по всему, это невозможно. Все действительно упирается в read only.

Comment: А может быть имеет место подмена задачи? Атомарность - странная цель. Для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать через ItemsSource. Т.е. вы готовите коллекцию отдельно, а потом говорите myCombo.ItemsSource = myCollection. Тогда Items сформируется автоматически на основе myCollection

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл уточнить, что речь идёт о WinForms а не о WPF.

Comment: Ох, нет, оказывается у WinForms ComBobox есть аналогичное свойство DataSource.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать AddRange, если я все правильно понял. Вот пример:

```
string[] s = { "1", "2", "3" };
var temp = new ComboBox();
temp.Items.AddRange(s); //присваиваем весь массив s
//присваиваем все элементы другого комбобокса
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(temp.Items.Cast<object>().ToArray<object>());
```

Comment: К сожалению, если операция выполняется в два действия (очищение, добавление) — это, гарантированно, неатомарная операция.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы стремитесь избежать изменения коллекции конкурирующими потоками, то вы можете использовать критические секции, для этого есть оператор lock

```
Object someLock = new Object();

lock (someLock) {
    // Меняем коллекцию
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем ставить задачу атомарного обновления списка `Item'`ов, следует уяснить, что обращения к `ComboBox` можно делать только в потоке пользовательского интерфейса. Поэтому риски, связанные с многопоточным доступом, в случае обновления содержимого выпадающего списка отсутствуют. Поэтому можете смело сохранить текущее содержимое в локальный список, обновить содержимое выпадающего списка, а если что-то упало - заполнить обратно тем, что предварительно сохранено, в блоке `catch`.